# React Native - Fetch using "json[0]" not working

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

Good day, so here I have two fetch and I use json[0] on these two fetchs because if not I'm having an error.

[image: Error]

Here's my code

```
export default class Settlement extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props)
        this.state = {
            ....
            numOrder: 0,
            TotalSum: 0
        };
    }
    fetchSum = async ( TotalSum ) => { 
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.254.100:3308/OrderNo/ForSum/" + this.state.orderDet)
        const json = await response.json()
        this.setState({ TotalSum: json[0].order_no })
    }
    fetchNumOrders = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.254.100:3308/NumOrder/num/" + this.state.orderDet)
        const json = await response.json()
        this.setState({ numOrder: json[0].order_no })
    }
render() {
    return (
        <View>
        ...
           <Text>Number of Orders: { this.state.numOrder }</Text>
           <Text>Total Amount: { this.state.TotalSum }</Text>
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

My out put:

[image]

Comment: Can you check that `numOrder` or `TotalSum` aren't objects?

Comment: like numOrder:[] and TotalSum:[] sir?